# Ellipsis Trouble: Passing ... to lm

Tags: r, lm, ellipsis

I am building a wrapper around `lm` to do some additional calculations. I'd like the wrapper to pass `...` to `lm`, but I am getting into trouble with `lm`'s `weights` argument.

```
LmWrapper <- function(df, fmla, ...) {
  est <- lm(fmla, df, ...)
  list(model = est)
}
```

If I call the wrapper with a weights argument,

```
data(airquality)
LmWrapper(airquality, Ozone ~ Wind, weights = Temp)
```

R does not know where to look for the weights:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

The `lm` help page says

> All of `weights`, `subset` and `offset` are evaluated in the same way as variables in `formula`, that is first in `data` and then in the environment of `formula`.

but the wrapper seems to change things.

How do I fix this?

---

The `traceback()` for the above error looks like this:

```
8: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
7: eval(extras, data, env)
6: model.frame.default(formula = fmla, data = df, weights = ..1, 
       drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
5: stats::model.frame(formula = fmla, data = df, weights = ..1, 
       drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(mf, parent.frame())
2: lm(fmla, df, ...) at #2
1: LmWrapper(diamonds, price ~ carat, weights = depth)
```

Calling `lm` directly, works just fine:

```
lm(Ozone ~ Wind, airquality, weights = Temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that `lm` normally looks up those names in argument data but somehow scoping goes wrong. You can fix that by looking up column references and passing them on manually.

```
LmWrapper <- function(df, fmla, ...) {
  # get names of stuff in ...
  argNames = sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1L], deparse)
  # look for identical names in df
  m = match(names(df), argNames, 0L)
  # store other arguments from ... in a list
  args = list(eval(parse(text = argNames[-m])))
  # name the list
  names(args) = names(argNames[-m])
  # store complete values in args, instead of just references to columns
  # the unlist code is rather ugly, the goal is to create a list where every
  # element is a column of interest
  args[names(argNames)[m]] = unlist(apply(df[, as.logical(m), drop = FALSE], 
                                       2, list), recursive = FALSE)
  # also put other stuff in there
  args$formula = fmla
  args$data = df
  # do lm
  est = do.call(lm, args)
  list(model = est)
}

data(airquality)

airquality$subset = airquality$Solar.R > 200
LmWrapper(airquality, Ozone ~ Wind, weights = Temp, subset = subset, 
          method = 'qr')
```

The code above is not the most beautiful, but it works for both `subset` and `weights`. Alternatively, you could just handle `weights` and `subset` as exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this answer @Vandenman. I just implemented it with two changes that I wanted to share, in case someone else comes across this thread:

1) If there are no arguments in ... apart from columns in the data, the code as above creates an NA element in the list, which throws a warning - I added a condition below to get around that.

2) The model object returned by the code above has a very very long call since it includes each weight etc. If you don't care about the ability to use `update()`, it might be more insightful to replace it by the actual function call to record what happened, as implemented below.

```r
run_lm <- function(df, formula, ...) {
    # get names of stuff in ...
    argNames = sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1L], deparse)
    # look for identical names in df
    m = match(names(df), argNames, 0L)

    # store other arguments from ... in a list, if any
    dot_args <- eval(parse(text = argNames[-m]))
    if (is.null(dot_args)) {args <- list()
    } else {
      args <- list(dot_args)
      # name the list
      names(args) = names(argNames[-m])
      }

    # store complete values in args, instead of just references to columns
    # the unlist code is rather ugly, the goal is to create a list where every
    # element is a column of interest
    args[names(argNames)[m]] = unlist(apply(df[, as.logical(m), drop = FALSE], 
                                            2, list), recursive = FALSE)
    # also put other stuff in there
    args$formula = formula
    args$data = df
    # do lm
   mod <- do.call(lm, args)
   mod$call <- sys.call()
   mod
   }
```