# Use of variable arguments (dot-dot-dot) in stats::lm in R

Tags: r, variadic-functions, lm

Suppose we have a function that makes a call to `stats::lm` and takes a formula and a data frame as arguments. Further arguments that we want to pass to `stats::lm` can be provided using variable arguments:

```
outer_function <- function(formula, data, ...) {
  z <- stats::lm(formula = formula, data = data, ...)
  return(z)
}
```

Now suppose we want to use this function and provide an additional argument (`weights`) that will be passed to `stats::lm`.

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(100)))
weights <- replicate(100, 1)
formula <- X1 ~ X2 + X3

outer_function(formula = formula, data = data, weights = weights)
```

This produces the following error in `stats::lm`:

```
Error in eval(extras, data, env) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

Debugging the call to `stats::lm` I see that argument `weights` is correctly passed to `stats::lm`, but `match.call()`, which is later used for evaluation in the function, is

```
stats::lm(formula = formula, data = data, weights = ..1)
```

such that `weights` is assigned the first element of the `...`-list, which is empty.

Can anybody elaborate on why this approach fails? In particular, if `weights` was a scalar (say 5) the problem would not arise and the `match.call()` would be

```
stats::lm(formula = formula, data = data, weights = 5)
```

For now, I am using the following solution for my function:

```
outer_function <- function(formula, data, ...) {
  args <- list(formula = formula, data = data, ...)
  z <- do.call(stats::lm, args)
  return(z) 
}
```

which works but I am still wondering whether there is no way around `do.call` in case the arguments in `...` are vectors or lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsis Trouble: Passing ... to lm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683076/ellipsis-trouble-passing-to-lm). It looks like your solution is neater than those proposed there already, so not sure you'll find a better solution.

Comment: thanks @caldwellst for your input. The post you shared essentially refers to the same problem and suggests a solution similar to mine. Hence I am able to solve the problem with do.call, but would like to understand (1) what "goes wrong" with my initial solution and (2) whether its possible to not use do.call somehow.

Comment: I don't think that this a duplicate question. The OP has explicitly asked about the technical details of _why_ the error was signaled. In my mind, that is quite distinct from the other question ("How do I fix this?"), which didn't invite much discussion about the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a work-around as safe and as succinct as `do.call`. I *can* explain what's going on, having debugged into the `lm` call.

In the body of `lm`, you'll find the statement

```
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
```

On the right hand side of the assignment, `mf` is the call

```r
stats::model.frame(formula = formula, data = data, weights = ..1, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

and `parent.frame()` is the frame of the `outer_function` call (in other words, the evaluation environment of `outer_function`). `eval` is evaluating `mf` in `parent.frame()`. Due to S3 dispatch, what is ultimately evaluated in `parent.frame()` is the call

```r
stats::model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = data, weights = ..1, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

In the body of `model.frame.default`, you'll find the statement

```r
extras <- eval(extras, data, env)
```

On the right hand side of *this* assignment, `extras` is the call

```r
list(weights = ..1)
```

specifying the arguments from `mf` matched to the formal argument `...` of `model.frame.default` (just `weights`, in this case, because `model.frame.default` *has* formal arguments named `formula`, `data`, and `drop.unused.levels`); `data` is the data frame containing your simulated data; and `env` is your *global environment*. (`env` is defined earlier in the body of `model.frame.default` as `environment(formula)`, which is indeed your global environment, because that is where you defined `formula`.)

`eval` is evaluating `extras` in `data` with `env` as an enclosure. An error is thrown *here*, because the data frame `data` and your global environment `env` are not valid contexts for `..n`. The symbol `..1` is valid only in the frame of a function with `...` as a formal argument.

You might have deduced the issue from `?lm`, which notes:

> All of `weights`, `subset` and `offset` are evaluated in the same way as variables in `formula`, that is first in `data` and then in the environment of `formula`.

There is no problem when `weights` is given the value of a constant (i.e., *not* the name of a variable bound in an environment and *not* a function call) in the `outer_function` call, because in that situation `match.call` does not substitute the symbol `..n`. Hence

```r
outer_function(formula = formula, data = data, weights = 5)
```

works (well, a *different* error is thrown), but

```r
weights <- 5
outer_function(formula = formula, data = data, weights = weights)
```

and

```r
outer_function(formula = formula, data = data, weights = rep(1, 100))
```

don't.